# Динамическое обновление json фала (node.js, mongodb)

Tags: node.js, yandex-maps-api, mongodb

Нужно выводить большое количество точек на Яндекс карты.
Использую метод [ObjectManager](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/object-manager/about-docpage/) из документации.
(данные берутся из json файла и выводятся на карту)

Не могу понять как динамически обновлять этот json файл используя node.js и mongodb. 
В базу данных каждые несколько минут/секунд будут добавляться новые координаты.

Answer (score 1):

Есть LOM https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/loading-object-manager/about-docpage/ и ROM https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/remote-object-manager/about-docpage/ они делают запрос за данными к вашему серверу. Вам нужно только правильно отвечать.